# Check if combination of values matches values in a range

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, match

I'm quite new to VBA and struggle with to following: I have a sheet of about 1000 rows, each row represents a client record. The first column is the clients id number, next 10 columns are the meds the client uses. I want to find which clients use a certain combination of meds. So, I have a form to select the meds, let's say combobox1 gives me Med1, combobox2 gives Med2 and so on until a combination of 5 meds. I know how to find how many clients use 1 selected med, but I have no clue how to find a combination. So, I want to find howmany clients uses the combo of med1 + med2 +...+ med5.
Can anyone help me with this? Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: It would help to see what code you have got so far (i.e. for counting on 1 column which you say you can do).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, there you go, though I had to make some assumptions:

```
Sub defineClients()

Dim chosenMeds(1 To 5)      As String
Dim ClientRange             As Range
Dim selectedClients         As Collection
Dim valid                   As Integer

Set selectedClients = New Collection
Set ClientRange = Range("A2:F1000") 'A = ClientID, B,C,D,E,F are Meds 1-5

For i = 1 To 1000 'Your number of clients

valid = 0

'Assume you can work this out from the ComboBox
chosenMeds(1) = "Med1"
chosenMeds(2) = "Med2"
chosenMeds(3) = "Med3"
chosenMeds(4) = "Med4"
chosenMeds(5) = "Med5"

    For j = 1 To 5 'Assuming every client has a list of 5 meds with no repeating(!!!)

        With ClientRange

            If _
        .Cells(i, 1 + j).Value = chosenMeds(1) Or _
        .Cells(i, 1 + j).Value = chosenMeds(2) Or _
        .Cells(i, 1 + j).Value = chosenMeds(3) Or _
        .Cells(i, 1 + j).Value = chosenMeds(4) Or _
        .Cells(i, 1 + j).Value = chosenMeds(5) _
        Then

            valid = valid + 1

        End If

    End With

Next j

If valid = 5 Then 'The client is valid

    selectedClients.Add ClientRange.Cells(i, 1).Value 'This collects the valid clients' ids

End If

Next i


End Sub
```

Hope this helps, but for it you have to be familiar w/ VBA to sheet communication to have yout proper output.

Answer (score 0):

Add a new column next to the existing ones and call it something like "valid".

in the column, you can use an if formula like `=if(AND(A:A=Med1,B:B=Med2,C:C=Med3),1,0)`

This example is basically looking at the column A (for the same row your formula is typed in), checking if it is the same as Med1, then looks at column B, checks if it is the same as Med2 etc. If it satisfies all of the conditions, it'll return a 1, if not, a 0. You can then use that column and do a sum at the bottom to see how many clients fulfill that combination and can filter to see exactly who they are.

You would have to carry on the stuff after the AND for all 10 of your columns. Med1, Med2 etc in my example will just link to whatever output is linked to your combo box. When you change your selection in the combo box, it'll look for that in the formula and change itself dynamically.